# Checking remote true on modal in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Rails 5 and bootstrap modal. I am trying to figure it out if there's a way to show a dismiss button if the user view the data in modal and a regular link to when its just a regular show rails page.

```
if modal || remote: true
show this:
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
else 
     <%= link_to "Cancel", contacts_path, class: "btn btn-outline-secondary border-button mt-n3", id: "cancel-btn", ":data-dismiss" => "modal" %>
end
```

Is there a work around here?

Answer (score 0):

From a view/partial perspective - there's no difference whether it's being rendered inside a modal, `remote:true` or not, so you have to pass that knowledge somehow. For example - using local variables of a partial:

```
<% in_modal ||= false %>
...
<% if in_modal %>
  <button...
<% else %>
  <%= link_to ... %>
<% end %>
```

```
<%= render partial: 'your_partial', locals:{ in_modal: true } %>
```

Comment: `$('#modal-show-body').html('<%= j render("show_single", locals:{ in_modal: true }) %>');` tried this but did not work

Comment: `show_single` is the partial that I am rendering via ajax